# Overriding in gradle a task imported from Ant

Tags: gradle

I import an ant script to a gradle build using:

```
ant.importBuild "build.xml"
```

I want to implement task `runSth` (existing in ant script) in better way, using gradle capabilities. However when I try to define it, I get:

```
Cannot add task ':runSth' as a task with that name already exists.
```

How to override an ant task in a gradle script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved on gradle-user mailing list ([nabble archive](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/gradle-user-f1431424.html)).

Adam Murdoch [advices](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/overriding-a-task-in-an-imported-Ant-build-tp1435046p1435047.html):

> You can trick the AntBuilder into thinking it has already imported the
>   'clean' task before you do the import:

```
ant.project.addTarget('runSth', new org.apache.tools.ant.Target())
ant.importBuild(...)
```

Works for me.